# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, web, laravel-5

I wrote the following code and fatal error occurred. I tried to find the mistakes and watched so many videos and posts but this error is killing me now.
Please tell me the errors in this code?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller {

    public function postSignUp(Request $request){
        $email=$request['email'];
        $first_name=$request['first_name'];
        $last_name=$request['last_name'];
        $password=bcrypt($request['password']);


        $user =new User();
        $user->email=$email;
        $user->first_name=$first_name;
        $user->last_name=$last_name;
        $user->password=$password;

        $user->save();

        return redirect()-> back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've not got your project started yet then remove the folder and start again following [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4) down to the tea. I've found that the `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` terminal command works the best on mac. Although thats just in my experience.